# Set column_titles and row_titles and the bottom and and the left of the plot using subplots in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

I’m using `from plotly.subplots import make_subplots` and I have two list for my column_ and row_titles:

```
col_name = list(df.columns)
row_name = col_name[::-1] # the inverse of col_name
fig = make_suplots(rows=5, cols=5,  start_cell="bottom-left", column_titles=col_name , row_titles=row_name )
```

I managed making somthing like that: (see picture)

[image]

As you can see the column_titles is on the top and the row_titles on the right side of the plot

It is possible to set the **column_titles on the bottom and the row_titles on the left side?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

```
fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a:  a.update(y = -0.2) if a.text in column_titles else a.update(x = -0.07) if a.text in row_titles else())
```

---

#### Plot

[image]

---

#### The details

Column and row labels are stored as `annotations` in `fig.layout.annotations`:

```
'layout': {'annotations': [{'font': {'size': 16},
                                'showarrow': False,
                                'text': 'A',
                                'x': 0.22,
                                'xanchor': 'center',
                                'xref': 'paper',
                                'y': 1.0,
                                'yanchor': 'bottom',
                                'yref': 'paper'},
```

Messing with annotations can quickly lead to problems since your procedures can manipulate elements that are not column or row labels. But in this case it's fairly easy to identify enough annotation attributes to ascertain that they are in fact the labels you're trying to edit. If, for example, `annotation[0].text` can be found in `column_titles`, ten you kan keep `'x': 0.22,` and change `'y': 1.0` to, for example, `'y': -0.2`. And that's exactly what the proposed approach does in the complete snippet below:

#### Complete code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

column_titles = ['A', 'B']
row_titles = ['1', '2']

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2, start_cell="bottom-left", 
                   column_titles = column_titles,
                   row_titles = row_titles)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[4, 5, 6]),
              row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[20, 30, 40], y=[50, 60, 70]),
              row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[300, 400, 500], y=[600, 700, 800]),
              row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[4000, 5000, 6000], y=[7000, 8000, 9000]),
              row=2, col=2)

fig.for_each_annotation(lambda a:  a.update(y = -0.2) if a.text in column_titles else a.update(x = -0.07) if a.text in row_titles else())

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer... But i already did it dynamicalli without column_ or row_titles

Comment: @herbigjson Cool! How?

Comment: Suppose my matrix is a 5*5 matrix:

`number = 5

for i,j in zip(range(1,number**2,number), range(1,number)):

         if i<number**2:

              print fig['layout']['yaxis{}'.format(i)]['title'] = rows[j]`


So i can get the name of all the first the y axis and i did the same for the first x axis (so the x axis on the bottom) :)